# Как реализовать триггер на проверку удаления нескольких обьектов

Tags: postgresql

Имеется вот такая таблица и триггер на проверку удаления к ней.

```
CREATE TABLE sections_children
(
section_id integer NOT NULL,
child_id integer NOT NULL,
pay_day DATE,
payment int CHECK(payment = 1 OR payment =0) DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TriggerTwoF() RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
IF(TG_OP = 'DELETE')THEN
 IF OLD.payment = 0 THEN
  RAISE EXCEPTION 'Имеется долг по секции %',OLD.section_id;
 ELSE
  RETURN NEW;
 END IF;
END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

REATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TriggerTwo
AFTER DELETE ON sections_children
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE TriggerTwoF()
```

вот я вставляю обьекты.

```
INSERT INTO sections_children VALUES (1,1,2022-04-01,1);
INSERT INTO sections_children VALUES (1,2,NULL,0);
```

Как можно реализовать этот триггер, чтобы работало удаление нескольких обьектов,а те обьекты которые не прошли проверку не удалились?

```
DELETE FROM sections_children WHERE child_id =1 OR 2
```

Comment: Вы хотите, чтоб операция delete пропускала записи у которых `payment = 0`? Вы не можете в рамках одной операции одновременно удалить одну запись и бросить исключение для другой.

Comment: да именно так .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Важно сделать две вещи:

1. триггер нужно сделать BEFORE DELETE, чтоб у него была возможность отменить удаление
2. В случае, когда не нужно удалять триггер должен возвращать `NULL`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TriggerTwoF() RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
IF(TG_OP = 'DELETE')THEN
 IF OLD.payment = 0 THEN
  RETURN NULL;
 ELSE
  RETURN OLD;
 END IF;
END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TriggerTwo
BEFORE DELETE ON sections_children
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE TriggerTwoF()
```

Еще замечание, вы похоже используете `payment` как булевскую переменную. Вместо ручной эмуляции просто используйте тип `BOOLEAN`, не нужно будет создавать вручную ограничения:

```
CREATE TABLE sections_children
(
section_id integer NOT NULL,
child_id integer NOT NULL,
pay_day DATE,
payment BOOLEAN DEFAULT false
);


... проверка
IF NOT OLD.payment THEN
```

Comment: спасибо большое.